# FOG Server NFS Issue

Tags: permissions, nfs, server-message-block, imaging, ghost

I am having an issue with the Free Open Ghost server. I set it up on Ubuntu server, and have Ubuntu mounting an SMB share to it's /images directory (my server has a small internal boot disk). Fog's web management interface sees the full capacity of my SMB share, but when I attempt to upload a system, I get a permissions error. The screen reads as follows:

```
* Preparing to send image file to server.
* Mounting File System................mount: 192.168.0.36:/images/dev/ failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
Done

Fatal Error: Failed to mount NFS Volume

Computer will reboot in 1 minute.
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It looks like it's trying to use NFS instead of SMB(/CIFS)?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't otherwise configured NFS, FOG will initialise your `/etc/exports` for you; then you need the following for `/images/dev/`:

- Permissions 0777 (mine is owned by `fog/root` but ownership may not be important)
- A dummy file called `.mntcheck` also with permissions 0777 (mine is owned by `root/root`, but again the ownership of this may not be important) - use e.g. `touch` to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your hardware information [IP ADDRESS] in the web server then try to relaunch again. Please check also the IP ADDRESS in FOG Settings in Web Server and TFTP Server. It should be the same IP in your PC that the server installed.

NOTE: Please use "Static IP".